# How to create a microservice that replicates itself as load of data increases?

Tags: twitter, streaming, microservices

Iam working on a  project of big data, where Iam trying to get tweets from Twitter and analyse these tweets and make predictions out of it.
I have followed this tutorial : http://blog.cloudera.com/blog/2012/10/analyzing-twitter-data-with-hadoop-part-2-gathering-data-with-flume/
 for getting the tweets. Now Iam planning to build a microservice which can replicate itself as I increase the number of topics on which I want tweets. Now whatever code I have written to gather the tweets with that  I want to make a microservice that can take a keyword and create a instance of that code for that keyword and gather tweets, for each keyword an instance should be created.
It will also be helpful if you inform me what tools to use for such application.
Thank you.

Comment: Microservices don't replicate themselves. The Orchestration layer for them manages deploying additional instances... If you want *autoscaling*, then deploy your apps in a cloud container service

Comment: @KeshavPradeepRamanath I have completed the entire tutorial, following the above given link, where I had created a entire environment where Apache flume was used to pull the tweets from Twitter to the hdfs system of Hadoop and the process was controlled by oozie and atlast the Jason data from the hdfs was queried using Apache hive, to get the number of retweets by a person.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I want to make a microservice that can take a keyword and create a instance of that code for that keyword and gather tweets, for each keyword an instance should be created.

You could use [kubernetes](https://kubernetes.io/) as an underlying cluster/deployment infrastructure. It has an [API](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/overview/kubernetes-api/) that allows you to deploy new services programmatically. So what you would have to do is:

- Set up a basic service container for your twitter-service that is available in a [container repository](https://www.aquasec.com/wiki/display/containers/What+is+a+Container+Image+Repository).
- Then you deploy a first [service](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/services-networking/service/) based on your container. The service configuration will [contain the keyword](https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/inject-data-application/define-environment-variable-container/) that the service uses as well as information about the kubernetes cluster (how to access the cluster API and where to find the container in the repository).
- Now your first service has all the information it needs to automatically create additional service descriptions for kubernetes (with other key words) and deploy those additional services by calling the kubernetes cluster API.
- Since the additional services will be passed all the necessary information as well, they themselves can then start even more services and so on.

You probably need to put some effort into figuring out the cluster provisioning, but that can also be done automatically with auto-scaling (available for Google or AWS clouds for example).

A different approach would be to run a horizontally scaled cluster of your basic twitter services that use a self organization algorithm to involve all the keywords put into a database or event queue.